# Valid Instruments for an IV/2SLS Regression for house prices

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I'm brand new here so my apologies if this is too general or has been answered elsewhere. I'm trying to estimate a model for the house prices that includes several endogenous regressors. For the sake of completeness, my model is:

Ph =β0 + β1Yd1 + β2Yd2 + β3Yd3 + β4Yd4 + β5Yd5 + β6Ir + β7Cb + β8Rm + β9T + β10Dun + β11 Dpo + u

where Ph is house prices, Yd1-Yd5 is the average disposable income for households within each income quintile (so to be clear, there are 5 averages, one for each income quintile), Ir is real residential investment, Cb is the volume of banking credit the private sector, Rm is the mortgage rate, T is taxation on immovable property, Dun is the unemployment rate and Dpo is the population growth rate. The data is time-series from 1977-2012.

Since my theoretical framework tells me several variables are likely to be endogenous (to be specific, Yd1-Yd5, Ir and Cb), I'm trying to estimate the model with instrumental variables regression using 2sls. When I had trouble coming up with valid instruments, my dissertation supervisor suggested I use lagged values of my exogenous variables as instruments. In my understanding of IV regression/2SLS, however, there are several problems with this:

1. To be valid, instruments need to be non-correlated with the error term *u*. However, the exogenous variables included in my model for house prices (that is, Rm, T, Dun and Dpo) are included precisely because they thought to be useful in explaining variation in the dependent variable (in this case, Ph). The lags of these variables therefore seem likely to correlated with house prices as well, which leads me to believe that they will be correlated with the error term *u*. When I discussed this with someone they suggested that it is not the same for a variable to be correlated with the dependent variable as it is for a variable to be correlated with the error term *u*. But isn't *u* just thought to contain extra variation in the dependent variable (above and beyond what the model accounts for)? So if a variable not included in the model (in this case, the lagged values of my exogenous variables that are being considered for use as instruments) is correlated with Y, shouldn’t it also be correlated with this “extra variation” and then automatically be correlated with *u*?
2. Supposing that lagged values of my exogenous regressors (Rm, T, Dun and Dpo) do represent valid instruments, it seems that using these as instruments would preclude me from using their lagged values as normal regressors. Since this seems a major loss, can anyone suggest a superior method for dealing with the endogeneity issues mentioned previously?

Thank you

Comment: A good place to start (and my standard response) is to consult the literature in your field.  A lot of the justification for instruments comes from theory and/or previous empirical findings.